# Voyager Laravel axios get 405

Tags: laravel, axios

What could be wrong that I get a 405 method not allowed if Im gonna use a **POST** but if I used **GET** it gives me 200.

This is my **Controller**

```
public function getAnken(Request $request)
{
   $from = $request->input('from');
   $to = $request->input('to');
   echo json_encode($request);
}
```

This is my **Axios in Vuejs**

```
axios.post('/admin/ankens',{
    from: '2018/05/28',
    to: '2018/05/29' 
})
.then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data)
});
```

This is my **web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
    Route::get('/ankens', 'AnkensController@getAnken');
});
```

And I put this in my **bootstrap.js** too

```
window.axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Voyager::routes();` overwrites the below route `Route::get('/ankens'`, to make it read first put it before.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::post('/ankens', 'AnkensController@getAnken');
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Be sure to use `URL/admin/slug-name` and `URL/admin/ankens` are identical but different http verb.

Comment: I still got an 405. Only when I use POST method but if I use GET I got 200.

Comment: use routes as `Route::post('/ankens'` not `get`

Comment: I see thank you sir I got it bdw it still ok even I didnt exchanged the `Route::post('/ankens'` and `Voyager::routes()`